# What does the phrase "negotiating with your baby's bedtimes and night-time wake-ups" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, verbs, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "negotiating with your baby's bedtimes and night-time wake-ups" here:

> Keep this sleep-tracker handy if you are negotiating with your baby's
> bedtimes and night-time wake-ups during their early years.

The text is from an offline source that contains the description of a sleep-tracking app.

Comment: It's a "tongue-in-cheek" usage. Parents don't *negotiate* bedtimes with babies! And they certainly don't get to negotiate middle-of-the-night "wake-up" times!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's negotiating with the *bedtimes,* not with the babies; this usage seems unidiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I sort of agree with alphabet. I think the author likely meant "negotiate" in the same sense as a driver "negotiates" a tight curve in the road. However, I don't think that I've ever seen it used intransitively with that meaning.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Drivers never "negotiate **with**" tight bends! The example text here is simply "invalid", and learners shouldn't be encouraged to think it's okay. Although the OP claims it's from an online course, Google reports no matches even for the string "if you are negotiating with your baby" - which is a "sorta" credible sequence, even though "...with your baby's bedtimes" could probably *never* be valid, no matter how contrived the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree entirely. I was only suggesting that that was what the author intended. (I don't know for sure, of course.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I'm as sure as I can be that you're correct as regards the writer's *intended* meaning. But it's not well expressed - and presumably people come here to learn correct and/or "normal" English, so we shouldn't give the impression that OP's cited example falls into either of those categories.